# Java reflection invoke on getDeclaringClass

Tags: java, reflection, java-8

I have a interface like this and some classes implemented this interface:

```
public interface MyInterface {}
public class Informations implements MyInterface {

    @Command("version")
    public void getVersion() {
        System.out.println("1.0-SNAPSHOT");
    }
}

public class Systems implements MyInterface {

    @Command("os")
    public void getOs() {
        System.out.println("Linux OS");
    }
}
```

I collecting all methods annotated `@Command` in a Map like this :

```
/* String is command */ 
private Map<String, Method> commandMaps = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

Now , I want invoke this methods :

```
Optional<String> optionalCommand = commandMaps.keySet().stream().filter(e -> e.equals(user_input_command)).findFirst();
if (optionalCommand.isPresent()) {
    Method method = commandMaps.get(optionalCommand.get());
    Class<?> declaringClass = method.getDeclaringClass();
    System.out.println(">> " + method.getName());
    System.out.println(">> " + declaringClass.getName());
    method.invoke(declaringClass);
}
```

for example user enter `os` command and declaringClass.getName() referenced to `Systems` class but can not invoking declaringClass .
so , this code result IllegalArgumentException exception :

```
>> getOs
>> a.b.c.Systems
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
```

How can fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke a method via reflection, you need to pass the object you are calling the method on as the first parameter to Method#invoke.

```
// equivalent to s1.testParam("", obj)
testParamMethod.invoke(s1, "", obj);
```